# is it possible to call different method of controller using single form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-form

I Have one form in laravel with table, table has some value of user such as[image]

above table i have buttons for selected check box such as `delete`, `copy details`, etc. so i need to call different methods of control.

Comment: Of course...you can set which ever you want....do you use Laravel Collective for forms? Like this {!! Form::open() !!}

Comment: Why dont you create a route for each operation and link to them?

Comment: I would do this with AJAX.

Comment: @Mick how is this possible using ajax??

Comment: Look at a tutorial like this: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-ajax-crud-with-pagination-example-and-demo-from-scratchexample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use AJAX and a Resource Controller.

You can then use REST verbs for each action.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. HTML5 adds a formaction attribute to a <button>, allowing it to override the forms url when clicked. You would still need one route per action.

```
<form method="post" action="/you-need-html5-error-page">
    <button formaction="/delete"> delete </button>
    <button formaction="/bedazzle> bedazzle </button>

    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="2">
</form>
```

> **formaction** - The URI of a program that processes the information submitted by the button. If specified, it overrides the action attribute of the button's form owner.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction